# Update a mongo json object

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to update a document but it doesn't update and it doesn't throw any errors.

```
type Course struct {
    ObjectId    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id, omitempty"`
    Id          string             `json:"id"`
    Title       string             `json:"title"`
    Description string             `json:"description"`
    Lessons     string             `json:"lessons"`
    Duration    string             `json:"duration"`
    Details     struct {
        Title             string `json:"title"`
        Instructor        string `json:"instructor"`
        Introduction      string `json:"introduction"`
        Topics            string `json:"topics"`
    } `json:"course_details"`
}
```

I was not sure if the `id` was the issue, so I manually entered it as a string, which had no effect.

```
func (r *CourseRepo) UpdateCourse(ctx context.Context, c *Course) error {
    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    objID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(c.Id)
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }

   filter := bson.D{
     {"_id", objID},
   }

    update := bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{
            {"title", c.Title},
            {"description", c.Description},
            {"lessons", c.Lessons},
            {"duration", c.Duration},
            {"course_details", c.Details},
        },
        },
    }

    clog.InfoCtx("Filter: %+v", log.Ctx{"filter ": filter})
    clog.InfoCtx("Update: %+v", log.Ctx{"update ": update})

    result, err := r.collection.UpdateByID(ctx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        clog.Error(err)

        return err
    }

    clog.InfoCtx("Update Result", log.Ctx{"result ": result})

    return nil
}
```

logs:

```
"msg":"Update Result","result ":{"MatchedCount":0,"ModifiedCount":0,"UpsertedCount":0,"UpsertedID":null}}
```

I have tried `UpdateMany` / `UpdateOne` and / `UpdateById`.

Small snip it of the json I am sending...

```
   {
        "id": "649411c5d1c770dd462bd181",
        "title": "Algorithms",
        "description": "An awesome course",
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I'm not missing anything, but I think you got the IDs mixed up :)
Try to change the filter to either:

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"_id", c.ObjectId},
}
```

or

```
filter := bson.D{
    {"id", c.Id},
}
```

*Update
Just recognized you are using UpdateByID() but you pass a filter, try passing `objID` itself or use UpdateOne() instead like:

```
    result, err := r.collection.UpdateByID(ctx, objID, update)
```

or

```
    result, err := r.collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)
```

Comment: The first one is correct. I have `_id` because it is the mongo default id and `id` which is the json string I send. I cannot send a string to `_id` because it will not map correctly.

Comment: If your Course.Id is unique as well it should also work. Just make sure you compare mgo object ids _or_ string ids :)

Comment: the`id` is always empty in the db. I only use it to in a "POST" and then map the `id` to `_id`.

Comment: I think I just spotted something and will add it to my answer

Comment: Thank you `r.collection.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update)` worked!!!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad we figured this out ^^

Answer (score -1):

I am fairly sure if you are passing JSON as

```
  "_id": "649411c5d1c770dd462bd181"
```

and this is somehow loaded into the `Course` struct, then `c.Id` is ending up a regular string, not a real `ObjectId`.   Later, in your `error` function, you call

```
primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
```

but `"649411c5d1c770dd462bd181"` is not a valid Go hex string; it needs a `0x` or `0X` as a prefix ([https://www.includehelp.com/golang/hexadecimal-literals.aspx#:~:text=Hexadecimal%20numbers&text=In%20Go%20programming%20language%2C%20a,either%20in%20Uppercase%20or%20Lowercase](https://www.includehelp.com/golang/hexadecimal-literals.aspx#:%7E:text=Hexadecimal%20numbers&text=In%20Go%20programming%20language%2C%20a,either%20in%20Uppercase%20or%20Lowercase)).

Try prepending `0x` e.g.:

```
    filter := bson.D{
        {"_id", primitive.ObjectIDFromHex('0x' + c.Id)}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. Sadly that did not work. That is the `_id` is the database I get from `GetAll` and can read on `https://account.mongodb.com/`. The json string I send in the body of the request is mapped to `Id   primitive.ObjectID bson:"_id, omitempty"`  in my struct.

Comment: I adjusted my struct and this is no longer an issue. I updated the post too. For some reason I cannot update!